# How to configure .env file in lumen?

Tags: mysql, database-migration, lumen

I have tried searching and asking friends, the internet or on this site but all failed, I want to migrate database in lumen and this is my .env setting

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_twin
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
UNIX_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

so when I enter php artisan migrate, I got this error

```
In Connection.php line 664:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = db_twin and table_name = migrations)

In Connector.php line 70:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: show us connection.php file

Comment: Why are you using UNIX_SOCKER? Using DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 should be sufficient. Probably that cause the no such file or directory since it links to a `tmp` folder, which is a bad idea